# find order by closest to number

Tags: sql, ruby, activemodel

How can I arrange order in
`Model.where(...).order()`
to sort the items based on proximity of a number field to assign number?

So, when I request to order for 4, (1...6) would be something like this: [4,5,3,6,2,1]

Comment: How do you decide whether 5 or 3 comes first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want the absolute value of the difference between a given number and the field value. For example:

```
User.order("abs(4 - <your-field-name-here>)")
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exacly what I was looking for :)